# c++ qt6 application deployment "this application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initalized"

Tags: c++, deployment, release, mingw-w64, qt6

i wanted to release-deploy some qt6 c++ mingw64 application, copied the necessary dll into the buildfolder where my application.exe was located, but when starting the application, it said "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized".

as mentioned in other posts, i tried windeployqt-qt6.exe on my application.exe, but without any change or success. While trying other stuff, i found out that if i copied mingw64/share/qt6 folder to my build folder to build/share/qt6, then the application started correctly. Am i doing this correctly? Or if not, how would you normally deploy some qt application?

Comment: If you don't want to copy the required dlls as well as the platform directory alongside your executable, you may be interested to use a [qt.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-conf.html) file.